# Analytic geometry straight line problem

Tags: analytic-geometry, geometry

Prove that two straight lines represented by the equation $x^3+y^3+bx^2y+cxy^2=0$ will be at right angles if $b+c=-2$

I didn't know that even straight lines like planes can be represented by a combined equation. can someone please explain how this happens and how to find the individual lines so that the angle between them may be determined.

Thanks

Comment: Well, this equation doesn't always represent two lines. It could also be one line or three lines. For instance, like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3+%2B+y^3+-+x^2*y+-+3*y^2*x+%3D+0).

Comment: @DanShved, I think that would imply the equation is equivalent to $(x+ry+s)^2(x+uy+v)=0$. (If his question is correct.)

Comment: @Easy Yep. But still, should we assume that there are indeed exactly two lines? Or does the question also asks us to prove this (when $b+c=-2$)? To sum up, I don't like the phrasing of the question )

Comment: How do we find combined equations of two or more straight lines ? like for plane we just do $\phi(x,y,z)*\theta(x,y,z)=0$

Comment: I thought the meaning of the question could be that $\,aw^2+bz^2=0\implies a=0=b\,$ , and from here the two lines...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the equation is homogeneous, so we let $x^3+y^3+bx^2y+cxy^2=(x+hy)^2(x+ky)$. Since we want two lines $x+hy=0,x+ky=0$ perpendicular, so $$(-\frac{1}{h})(-\frac{1}{k})=-1\Rightarrow hk=-1.$$Equating the corresponding coefficients gives $$h^2k=1,~2h+k=b,~h^2+2hk=c\Rightarrow h=-1,k=1\Rightarrow b=c=-1$$Thus, we have $b+c=-2$.

---

The converse: Assuming $b+c=-2$ we have $h^2+2hk+2h+k=-2$, that is $$(h^2+2h+1)+(1+2hk+k)=0\Leftrightarrow(h+1)^2+(h^2k+2hk+k)=0\Leftrightarrow(h+1)^2(k+1)=0$$So $h=-1,~k=-1$. But $h^2k=1$ forces that $h=-1,k=1$.

Comment: You have shown that *if* the lines are orthogonal, *then* $b+c=-2$. The question asked about the opposite direction.

Comment: @MvG, in fact we can obtain it as a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have silly question though. A first degree equation in x,y,z represents a plane. And a pair of plane represents a line through their intersection. so how did you take equation of two lines as $(x+hy)$ and $(a+ky)$ ? Should they rather not be equation of two planes? am i missing out on something ?

Comment: @AmanMittal, the equation only involves $x,y$, so the graph should be in $xy$-plane, in which case the general line equation is $Ax+By=C$.

Comment: Ah !! Thats the point. Thanks  a lot, i was working on 3D too much lately and missed out this simple point. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If by "lines represented by..." is meant that

$$0=x^3+y^3+bx^2y+cxy^2=x^2\color{red}{(x+by)}+y^2\color{red}{(y+cx)}\implies$$

the lines $by+x=0\;,\;\;y+cx=0\,$ are perpendicular to each other iff the product of their slopes is minus one, i.e. iff

$$-\frac1b\cdot (-c)=-1\iff -b=c\iff b+c=0$$

so either I'm misunderstanding the meaning of "representing the lines..." or else there's a mistake in the claim.

BTW, at the beginning,

$$b=0\implies x=0\;,\;\;\text{and then it should be}\;y=0\iff c=0\;\text{for the lines to be perpendicular}$$

as both the lines have zero free coefficient

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how can we pick the red portion of the equation (written by you) to be two lines ? aren;t they equations of planes anyway

Comment: @AmanMittal, I explained my mind in the comments below the question: my thought is that *perhaps* what is meant here is to use the relation for non-negative real numbers $\,aw^2+bz^2=0\implies a=b=0\,$ , with $\,a,b\,$ being, in our case, the expressions in red in my answer. I'm not completely sure whether this is what is meant in your question, though...

Comment: Yet inputting $\,x^3+y^3+3x^y-5xy^2=0\,$ in WA  gives indeed three lines and not only two, just as one of the users already mentioned...

Comment: You should be multiplying the expressions for the individual lines, not adding them as you seem to be doing in your first equation.

Comment: @MvG, that's why I *explained* what I tried to do. Since the usual did *not* give two but three lines (at least in several cases), Mine is an alternative approach. I still am not sure what the OP really meant...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two lines through the origin, one of slope $\alpha$ and the other of slope $\beta$:

\begin{align*}
l_1:\quad y &= \alpha x & \alpha x - y &= 0 \\
l_2:\quad y &= \beta x & \beta x - y &= 0
\end{align*}

Then you can multiply (powers of) these euqations to obtain a combined equation, which will be zero if and only if one of its factor polynomials is zero:

\begin{align*}
l_1^2 \cdot l_2&: &
\alpha^{2} \beta x^{3}
- (\alpha^{2} + 2 \, \alpha \beta) x^{2} y
+ (\beta + 2 \, \alpha) x y^{2}
- y^{3}
&= 0\\
l_1 \cdot l_2^2&: &
\alpha \beta^{2} x^{3}
- (\beta^{2} + 2 \, \alpha \beta) x^{2} y
+ (\alpha + 2 \, \beta) x y^{2}
- y^{3}
&= 0
\end{align*}

But these equations don't have the required form. It is enough to concentrate on the first equation, since $l_1$ and $l_2$ are structurally equivalent, so you might as well swap them. To turn $l_1^2\cdot l_2$ into the required form, you should multiply it with $-1$ in order to get $+y^3$ instead of $-y^3$. Then you get a monomial of $+x^3$ exactly if $\alpha^2\beta=-1$. So we now want

\begin{align*}
\alpha^2\beta &= -1 &
\\
\alpha^2 + 2\alpha\beta &= b &
\\
\beta + 2\alpha &= -c
\\
b + c &= -2
\end{align*}

Typing this in e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=alpha%5E2%2abeta=-1,%20alpha%5E2%2b2%2aalpha%2abeta=b,%20beta%2b2%2aalpha=-c,%20b%2bc=-2) you will get one real and two complex solutions:

\begin{align*}
b &= -1 & b &= -1-2i & b &= -1+2i \\
c &= -1 & c &= -1+2i & c &= -1-2i \\
\alpha &= 1 & \alpha &= -i & \alpha &= i \\
\beta &= -1 & \beta &= 1 & \beta &= 1 \\
\alpha\beta &= -1 & \alpha\beta &= -i & \alpha\beta &= i
\end{align*}

The real solution satisifes your requirement: the slopes multiply to $-1$, so the lines are orthogonal. Moreover, there is only a single pair of lines with that property. The complex solutions don't satisfy your requirement, but you'll probably want to exclude these from your consideration in any case.